# canvas/webgl based 3d community platform (open source)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl, three.js

I've been looking at three.js for a while and I was wondering if there are any open-source platforms that currently exist which provide a 3d community experience. There were many of these back in the days of VRML and X3D, just wondering if anyone has developed anything of this sort yet.

In other words:

- 3d multi-user worlds
- realtime chat
- objects/items
- accounts
- 1st person + avatars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, It doesn't exist yet. Altough I've seen several games/platforms in development. The closest one I know, that has most of your implmentations is [Cloud Party](https://its.cloudpartytime.com/) which is built webgl, not on Three.js.